# Increase the number of colors displayed on a (Geographical) map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have the following data in R (geographical map of North Carolina):

```
library(sf)  

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')


set.seed(123) 
nc$unemployement_rate <- runif(nrow(nc), 0,1)
```

For this data, I made the following visualization:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a map of North Carolina counties
g1 = ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc,
            aes(fill = cut_number(unemployement_rate, 9)),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd",
                      name = "unemployement_rate") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Unemployement Rate in North Carolina counties") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Suppose I want to add more "shades" (i.e. values) to the legend. Naturally, I thought I could do this by modifying the `cut_number()` function to include more ranges:

```
ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc,
            aes(fill = cut_number(unemployement_rate, 10)),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd",
                      name = "unemployement_rate") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Unemployement Rate in North Carolina counties") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

However, this gives me the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
  n too large, allowed maximum for palette YlOrRd is 9
Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

As I see, it seems like the built-in color palette I am using is only able to generate 9 colors at most. Anything else is not permitted.

**I was wondering if there was some way to "go around" this warning message and show more colors on the map.**

For example, in my case - suppose I want 10 ranges (0-10%, 11-21%, etc.) with each of these ranges becoming progressively darker.

Are there some alternate "strategies" I can use to modify my map to allow for more colors?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the tags, it will attract users who are familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a generic ggplot2 problem than a spatial data problem - but an interesting problem it is!

The palettes in `{RColorBrewer}` package contain a finite number of colors, known & tested to work well together. A lot of effort was put in curating them, which puts a limit of the number of colors in each palette set.

You can use `grDevices::colorRampPalette()` to interpolate from them. I am not aware of any hard limit on the interpolation, but you will lose the benefit of careful curation in the original package.

Consider this piece of code; what it does is:

- increases the cut size from 10 (which differs only a little from the original 9) to 15
- swaps `scale_fill_brewer` for `scale_fill_manual`, using not the palette (which expects a function) but values argument (which expects a vector of values)
- provides 15 values of colors interpolated from original 9 colors of the YlOrRd palette by Cynthia Brewer

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc,
          aes(fill = cut_number(unemployement_rate, 15)),
          alpha = 0.8,
          colour = 'white',
          size = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd"))(15),
                    name = "unemployement_rate") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
       title = "Unemployement Rate in North Carolina counties") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image: north carolina with 15 colors]

Comment: @ Jindra Lacko: Thank you for your answer! I also attempted to solve this problem myself and posted an answer - can you please take a look at it if you have time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OP here - my own attempt:

```
library(sf)  
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')


set.seed(123) 
nc$unemployement_rate <- runif(nrow(nc), 0,1)


library(grDevices)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd"))(10)


ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc,
            aes(fill = cut_number(unemployement_rate, 10)),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = myPalette,
                      name = "unemployement_rate") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Unemployement Rate in North Carolina counties") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image]

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

**Note:** Optional Zooming Option (in case anyone is interested)

```
# E.g. Duke University
center_lat <- 36.0014
center_lon <- -78.9382


x_range <- 0.5
y_range <- 0.5

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc,
            aes(fill = cut_number(unemployement_rate, 10)),
            alpha = 0.8,
            colour = 'white',
            size = 0.3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = myPalette,
                      name = "unemployement_rate") +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
         title = "Unemployement Rate in North Carolina counties") +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank()) +
    coord_sf(xlim = c(center_lon - x_range, center_lon + x_range),
             ylim = c(center_lat - y_range, center_lat + y_range),
             datum = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, I believe your solution follows along the same lines of thought I proposed (scale fill manual & ramped up palette). Perhaps somewhat cleaner than mine due to putting the ramped up palette to the `myPalette` variable. Glad it works for you!